# Loud bang 2-3 times per day from Hitachi refrigerator

Tags: refrigerator, noise

I have a new Hitachi refrigerator which works fine but it gives a loud bang 2-3 times per day. The bang is a single sound, it's not repetitive. It happens at irregular intervals, sometimes there's only one hour between two bangs but most of the time it can be 12-24 hours between them. Sometimes it is so loud that it wakes me up in the middle of the night while I'm sleeping in a different room and with a fan going on in the room. The sound does not appear to be coming from *inside* the refrigerator because it is very clear and not muffled.

What can be the cause of this? Could it be contraction? I've had loud contractions of AC units wake me up at night before but never in a different room. Can contraction be so loud? Is the coolant popping?

Comment: Ice cubes falling into the ice tray perhaps? Try turning off the ice maker and see if the sound goes away.

Comment: Ice maker is turned off.

Comment: If it is new, would have the store or Hitachi care for it.  Does not seem like normal operation of a new fridge under warranty.  Might just be something loose or a defect.  Did you check that it is level, side to side and front to back?